# Al compilar este programa en Fortran, da algunos errores

Tags: compilar, fortran

Errores en Fortran al compilar el programa que funciona con archivos .dat o .txt.

Programa

```
Program liga

    Implicit none

        integer :: i,j,suma
        integer, parameter :: N = 4, M = 20
        real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
        u(3)= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)

        open (UNIT = 8, FILE = 'partidos.dat')
        open (UNIT=9, FILE= 'puntos.dat')


        read (8,*)
        read (8,*)
        read (8,*)

            do i= 2,N

            read (8,*) A(i,j) 

            end do 

            do i=1,N

              suma=0.0 

               do j= 1,3 

                 suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)

               end do 

               p(j)=suma

            end do 

       write (9,*) 
       write (9,*) 'Puntos de los equipos'
       write (9,*)

       write (9,*) p(j)


end program
```

Los errores que arroja:

```
gfortran -Wall -o "programa_liga" "programa_liga.f90" (in directory: /Users/joaquinbenavente/Desktop/TFS)
programa_liga.f90:2:1:
  Program liga
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:4:1:
   Implicit none
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:6:1:
    integer :: i,j,suma
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:7:1:
    integer, parameter :: N = 4, M = 20
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:8:1:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:9:1:
    u(3)= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:11:1:
    open (UNIT = 8, FILE = 'partidos.dat')
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:12:1:
    open (UNIT=9, FILE= 'puntos.dat')
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:15:1:
    read (8,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:16:1:
    read (8,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:17:1:
    read (8,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:19:1:
     do i= 2,N
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:21:1:
     read (8,*) A(i,j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:23:1:
        end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:25:1:
        do i=1,N
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:27:1:
          suma=0.0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:29:1:
           do j= 1,3
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:31:1:
             suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:31:12:
             suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)
            1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
programa_liga.f90:33:1:
           end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:35:1:
           p(j)=suma
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:37:1:
        end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:39:1:
      write (9,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:40:1:
      write (9,*) 'Puntos de los equipos'
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:41:1:
      write (9,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:43:1:
      write (9,*) p(j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:46:1:
  end program
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:8:12:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
            1
Error: Variable ‘i’ cannot appear in the expression at (1)
programa_liga.f90:8:14:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
              1
Error: Variable ‘j’ cannot appear in the expression at (1)
programa_liga.f90:8:16:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
                1
Error: The module or main program array ‘a’ at (1) must have constant shape
programa_liga.f90:8:20:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
                    1
Error: Variable ‘j’ cannot appear in the expression at (1)
programa_liga.f90:8:22:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
                      1
Error: The module or main program array ‘p’ at (1) must have constant shape
programa_liga.f90:8:25:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
                         1
Error: Variable ‘j’ cannot appear in the expression at (1)
programa_liga.f90:8:27:
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
                           1
Error: The module or main program array ‘u’ at (1) must have constant shape
programa_liga.f90:9:3:
    u(3)= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
   1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
Compilation failed.
```

---

Después de algunos cambios el programa es el siguiente:

```
Program liga

    Implicit none

        integer :: i,j,suma
        integer, parameter :: N = 4, M = 20
        real:: A(N,M), p(M),u(M)
        real:: u(3)
        u= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)

        open (UNIT = 8, FILE = 'partidos.dat')
        open (UNIT=9, FILE= 'puntos.dat')


        read (8,*)
        read (8,*)
        read (8,*)

            do i= 2,N

            read (8,*) A(i,j) 

            end do 

            do i=1,N

              suma=0.0 

               do j= 1,3 

                 suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)

               end do 

               p(j)=suma

            end do 

       write (9,*) 
       write (9,*) 'Puntos de los equipos'
       write (9,*)

       write (9,*) p(j)


end program
```

Los errores son:

```
   gfortran -Wall -o "programa_liga" "programa_liga.f90" (in directory: /Users/joaquinbenavente/Desktop/TFS)
programa_liga.f90:2:1:
  Program liga
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:4:1:
   Implicit none
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:6:1:
    integer :: i,j,suma
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:7:1:
    integer, parameter :: N = 4, M = 20
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:8:1:
    real:: A(N,M), p(M),u(M)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:9:1:
    real:: u(3)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:9:11:
    real:: u(3)
           1
Error: Symbol ‘u’ at (1) already has basic type of REAL
programa_liga.f90:10:1:
    u= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:12:1:
    open (UNIT = 8, FILE = 'partidos.dat')
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:13:1:
    open (UNIT=9, FILE= 'puntos.dat')
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:16:1:
    read (8,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:17:1:
    read (8,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:18:1:
    read (8,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:20:1:
     do i= 2,N
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:22:1:
     read (8,*) A(i,j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:24:1:
        end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:26:1:
        do i=1,N
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:28:1:
          suma=0.0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:30:1:
           do j= 1,3
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:32:1:
             suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:32:12:
             suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)
            1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
programa_liga.f90:34:1:
           end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:36:1:
           p(j)=suma
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:38:1:
        end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:40:1:
      write (9,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:41:1:
      write (9,*) 'Puntos de los equipos'
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:42:1:
      write (9,*)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:44:1:
      write (9,*) p(j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:47:1:
  end program
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
programa_liga.f90:10:3:
    u= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
   1
Error: Different shape for array assignment at (1) on dimension 1 (20 and 3)
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Hola Joaquin, bienvenido. sustituye la foto por el texto del codigo (si no sabes formatearlo ya te lo edito yo despues :D ) . Un saludo

Comment: Gracias Lois6b, ya he hecho lo que me dijiste. Gracias por tu ayuda de verdad.

Comment: Vale listo. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Si hace falta algo más, dime. Gracias.

Comment: Si, como comentario adicional recuerda que para formatear el codigo has de seleccionarlo y pulsar `ctrl+k` o pulsar el icono con el dibujo `{}`

Comment: Vale muchas gracias. Entonces usted podría ayudarme con esto?

Comment: No, no conozco Fortran en absoluto.  (recuerda borrar los comentarios que no aporten nada como los de agradecimiento. asi dejamos la pregunta más limpia ^^)

Answer (score 1):

[Fuente original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987331/silence-the-warning-non-conforming-tab-character-in-gfortran)

El caracter tabulador no forma parte del estándar de fortran.

La compilación con `-Wall` supone lo siguiente:

> -Wall
>
> > Enables commonly used warning options pertaining to usage that we recommend avoiding and that we believe are easy to avoid. This currently includes -Waliasing, -Wampersand, -Wconversion, -Wsurprising, -Wc-binding-type, -Wintrinsics-std, **-Wno-tabs**, -Wintrinsic-shadow, -Wline-truncation, -Wtarget-lifetime, -Wreal-q-constant and -Wunused.

El flag destacado en negro implica que el compilador no deja utilizar tabuladores en la codificación.

Para silenciar este error prueba a compilar con `-Wtabs`

Vamos con los errores:

```
    integer :: i,j,suma
    integer, parameter :: N = 4, M = 20
    real:: A(i,j), p(j),u(j)
```

¿Qué dimensiones van a tener los arrays `A`, `p` y `u`? Los arrays deberían tener dimensiones conocidas y desde luego no pueden venir de variables salvo si éstas están declaradas como `parameter`:

```
    real:: A(4,20), p(20),u(20)

    real:: A(N,M), p(M),u(M)
```

Otro problema con arrays:

```
    u(3)= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
```

Si justo en la línea anterior has declarado `u` como un vector... ¿Por qué intentas asignar 3 valores a una de las posiciones del vector? Eso no va a funcionar. Tienes que inicializar `u` con el juego de valores (sin usar índices):

```
    real:: u(3)
    u= (/3.0,1.0,0.0/)
```

Otro detalle:

```
suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)
```

Esta instrucción está mal... ¿Pretendes asignar a `p(j)` el valor de `suma`? ¿Lo contrario? ¿Esa última asignacion es un operador de suma,resta,...? Me es complicado poner código en este punto porque no termino de entender qué pretendes hacer con `p(j)` en este punto.

---

Nuevo errores:

1. estás redeclarando `u`

   ```
   real:: A(N,M), p(M),u(M)
   real:: u(3)
   ```
2. La suma siguene estando mal

   ```
   suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))= p(j)
   ```

Si lo que quieres es asignar el valor de `suma` a `p(j)` entonces debes hacer algo así:

```
suma=suma+(A(i,j)*u(j))
p(j) = suma
```

Comment: gracias, pero ese error no es tan relevante como los de abajo que realmente son los que me están dando dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Entre tantos warnings no había visto el error... ahora le echo un ojo

Comment: Vale gracias. Abajo del todo hay unos cuantos errores; si me puedes ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Joaquin echa un vistazo a la respuesta, que la he editado

Comment: Vale, he editado el código, lo publico ahora para que puedas verlo. Con el tema de p(j) queremos que, con el fichero creado, asigne la segunda columna de la matriz del dichero a esa operación.

Comment: Listo, queremos hacer un programa que devuelva un archivo con los puntos de cada equipo de fútbol, ya que en el fichero hemos puesto los partidos que ha ganado y que ha empatado cada equipo.

Comment: @Joaquin, este portal no está destinado que te hagamos los deberes sino a resolver dudas. Por otro lado en el tema de la declaración de los arreglos te he puesto un ejemplo con `M` y `N` para que veas que compila, no porque debas declararlo así a la fuerza... lo que tienes que hacer es comprender las respuestas, no copiarlas literalmente

Comment: @Joaquin por otro lado... si editas la pregunta y borras el contenido que ha dado pie a mi respuesta invalidas su contenido. Las ediciones han de mantener el contenido antiguo si éste es relevante en las respuestas que se ofrecen.

Comment: No son deberes en sí, este es solo un primer paso para una posterior realización de otro programa general. Llevamos dos semanas intentando que compile, hasta madrugadas, pero tenemos que entregarlo en dos días y nos estamos volviendo locos.

Comment: @Joaquin deberíais empezar por coger un manual de Fortran y entender su sintaxis y su funcionamiento... yo no soy experto en Fortran y la respuesta que os he dado la he fabricado buscando en Internet y usando un compilador online...

Comment: Vale gracias por ello, pero si únicamente me pudiera responder a por que el compilador me dice que un error es "unclassificable statement", si están todos declarados correctamente...

Comment: @Joaquin He actualizado la respuesta... y por favor, por respeto a quien te responde te agradecería que leyeses la respuesta completa... el error de la suma ya te lo había comentado en la primera edición.

Comment: Vale, todo ya está listo pero sigue dando todo el rato la respuesta de

Comment: Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Comment: @Joaquin Eso es porque, como te he dicho, por un lado no entiendes el lenguaje y, por otro, no estás entendiendo la respuesta. Estás dejando la declaración `u(M)` y, teniendo en cuenta que `M` vale 20, al compilador no le hace gracia que le intentes asignar a `u` un vector de 3 elementos.

Comment: No, eso ya lo hemos cambiado, hemos asignado un nuevo valor h, y luego hemos puesto u(h) habiendo declarado h=3.

Comment: Por lo que debería de funcionar

Comment: @Joaquin Habrás hecho algo mal. Como te digo, este es un sitio para preguntas y respuestas no una sala de chat. Si tienes problemas nuevos lo lógico es que crees diferentes preguntas... si resulta que las preguntas no son consistentes o son copias una de las otras te las cerrarán. Por supuesto todo esto parte de la base de que tu tienes que aportar tu granito de arena en forma de esfuerzo y conocimiento y si no conoces el lenguaje poco se puede hacer.